# Filter rows using %in%?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, `data`, consisting of:

```
Name           House Street    Apt  City    Postal  Phone
BARRY GORDON    106  SOME DR       A PLACE  Z4K4N2  999-828-7555
ANDERSON TAM    110  SOME DR       A PLACE  Z4K4N2  999-542-7555
BUCKLE J L S    117  SOME DR       A PLACE  Z4K4N2  999-212-7555
```

I have another dataframe, `dnc`, read in from `read_excel`:

```
Last Name   Address #   Street Name
Anderson                  Some Dr
Cibrian       PO          Box
Pistell       PO          Box
```

I want to exclude all rows that match `dnc[,1]` and `data$Street` AND the same Street Name in data. So 'Anderson' in `data$Name` and 'Some' in `data$Street` would delete that row. Notice the difference in capitals in both dfs. I tried manually/hardcode testing and still couldn't get what I wanted. I have been trying:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(data, dnc[,1] %in% data$Name & dnc[,3] %in% data$Street)
```

and

```
avector <- as.vector(dnc[,1])
data[data$Name %in% avector, ] 

typeof(data$Name)
[1] "character"
```

Thanks

Comment: it's generally bad practice to refer to columns by their number -- in the long term, the columns may shift around, leading to problems that may be hard to detect. The code will also be much easier if you use the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you test if this work:

```
library(dplyr)

# Modify entries 
data$NameMod <- tolower(gsub(" .*", "", data$Name))
data$StrMod <- tolower(data$Street)
dnc$`Last Name` <- tolower(dnc$`Last Name`)
dnc$`Street Name` <- tolower(dnc$`Street Name`)

# Filter data using dplyr
filter(data, !NameMod %in% dnc$`Last Name` & 
             StrMod %in% dnc$`Street Name`)
```

Result using @ycw [dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46228432/1286528):

```
          Name House  Street Apt  City Postal        Phone NameMod  StrMod
1 BARRY GORDON   106 SOME DR   A PLACE Z4K4N2 999-828-7555   barry some dr
2 BUCKLE J L S   117 SOME DR   A PLACE Z4K4N2 999-212-7555  buckle some dr
```

I can't use data that you provided so had to write this blindly. First you have to modify your data (e.g. remove text that goes after `Anderson` and turn everything to lower case), then filter by entries in `dnc`.

Comment: Error in gsub(".*", data$Name) : argument "x" is missing, with no default. Im not quite sure what you wanted with that or id fix it

Comment: @sn0mmis fixed                    .

Comment: @PoGibas You can use my code to load the data and test your code. I think "filter(data, !(NameMod %in% dnc$`Last Name` & StrMod %in% dnc$Address))" is the right one.

Comment: So upon running, it took out last name 'Kerr' with a dnc street name of 'cantle' when the real match was supposed to be 'Kerr' with 'Bluestone Dr'. It took out 'Hughes' with a dnc street name of blank when the real 'Hughes' should be with Street 'Bluestone Dr'. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: @sn0mmis does this solution work for you? You can accept it then

Comment: I upvoted it. Do I need to do something more? I ended up filtering by phone number instead if it matters.

Comment: @sn0mmis just click accept (green arrow) so we can close this

Answer (score 2):

I think you need regular expression to find matching string instead of `%in%`.

The following is an example using `grepl` and the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(!(grepl(paste0(unique(dnc$`Last Name`), collapse = "|"), Name, ignore.case = TRUE) &
           grepl(paste0(unique(dnc$Address), collapse = "|"), Street, ignore.case = TRUE)))
          Name House  Street Apt  City Postal        Phone
1 BARRY GORDON   106 SOME DR   A PLACE Z4K4N2 999-828-7555
2 BUCKLE J L S   117 SOME DR   A PLACE Z4K4N2 999-212-7555
```

`paste0(..., collapse = "|")` creates a regular expression pattern testing the elements with `OR`. `ignore.case = TRUE` makes the matching ignores the differences in cases. `&` means two `grepl` condition needs to both be satisfied. `!` indicates the opposite condition.

**DATA**

```
library(dplyr)

data <- read.table(text = "Name           House Street    Apt  City    Postal  Phone
'BARRY GORDON'    106  'SOME DR'       A PLACE  Z4K4N2  999-828-7555
                   'ANDERSON TAM'    110  'SOME DR'       A PLACE  Z4K4N2  999-542-7555
                   'BUCKLE J L S'    117  'SOME DR'       A PLACE  Z4K4N2  999-212-7555",
                   header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dnc <- read.table(text = "'Last Name'   Address
Anderson                  'Some Dr'
Cibrian       'PO          Box'
Pistell       'PO          Box'",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dnc <- dnc %>% rename(`Last Name` = Last.Name)
```

Comment: it seems to have taken out too many rows when I checked in excel

Comment: It works for the example you provided. So your real world data must be different than the example you provided.

Comment: yeah, trying to figure that out now. thanks for the responses ycw.